# Appending Extra Path Information to @MultipartConfig(location = "/")

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, file-upload, java-ee-7

I am developing a simple file uploader. The simple file uploader adds supposed to upload various files (image/***, video/***, audio/***, text/*** and application/***) to image, video, audio, text and application directories respectively. I have problems appending a path(e.g. video/) to the current directory specified in @MultipathConfig(location = "/files/uploads") annotation. I want a path for an uploaded video to be /files/uploads/video/aws_signs_javas_creator.mp4
I'm developing in Netbeans 8.02, GlassFish Server 4.0 on Ubuntu.

index.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

FileUploader.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "FileUploader", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig(location = "/files/upload")
public class FileUploadController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part -> "file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        InputStream fileContent = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String fileType = null;
        for (Part filePart : fileParts) {
            if (filePart.getSize() != 0) {
                fileName = Decorator.getFileName(filePart);
                fileType = filePart.getContentType();

                fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
                filePart.write(location + fileName);

                if(fileType.contains("image/")) {
                    filePart.write("/images/" + fileName);
                } else if(fileType.contains("application/")) {
                    filePart.write("/applications/" + fileName);
                } else if(fileType.contains("video/")) {
                    filePart.write("/videos/" + fileName);
                } else if(fileType.contains("text/")) {
                    filePart.write("/texts/" + fileName);
                } else if(fileType.contains("audio/")) {
                    filePart.write("/audios/" + fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private String getFileName(final Part part) {
        final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
        for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")){
            if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return content.substring(
                        content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible causes of the error:

You pass in a file name which starts with a `/`. Maybe Glassfish then does not write it relative to the upload directory but to the absolute location. Therefore try

```
filePart.write("images/" + fileName);
```

etc.

If the subdirectory does not exist yet, the writing of the part may also fail. (That happens in Tomcat).

In both cases the server logfile hopefully contains hints about what is going wrong.

Comment: Here's the exception caught:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nkengbeza/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/FilesUploader/files/uploads/images/jquery-logo.png (No such file or directory) . I want my upload path to be: /home/nkengbeza/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/iles/uploads/images/jquery-logo.png

Comment: @byteHunt3r seems to me that Glassfish is ignoring your location specified in the `@MultipathConfig` annotation and/or misimplements the Servlet spec regarding the write location. As a workaround you could just use the InputStream of the Part and write it yourself to a location instead of relying on the troublesome `Part.write(String)`.